# How can I get to the third table with an association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

A process has a `Request`, then after approval, an `Order` is created. At last, the customer gets a `PaymentRequest` for the orders he made.

In the `Request`, there is a `project_id`, so in `request model`:

```
belongs_to :project
```

The `Order model` is connected to a `Request`:

```
belongs_to :request
```

And every `PaymentRequest`:

```
has_many :orders
```

What should I do in the `PaymentRequest` model and other models so I would be able to get the `project` from `Request`?

So I would like to do something like:

```
PaymentRequest.where("requests.project_id = ?").joins(???)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
PaymentRequest.joins(orders: :request).where("requests.project_id = ?", some_id)
```

or as suggested by Frederik:

```
PaymentRequest.joins(orders: :request).where(requests: { project_id: some_id })
```

Comment: or maybe even `.where(requests: { project_id: some_id })`